# Why FeathersUI Label cuts letters

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, starling-framework

I develop my app with AIR, Starling and FeatherUI for iOS.

I use Label with TextBlockTextRenderer (flash.text.engine.TextBlock).

I faced the following problem: http://monosnap.com/image/1chKMEoG2fDufCMJIdrgcX3dcTbLMa

In short: Some parts of letters are being cut. (this issue affect languages that has high glyphs, like Norway, German, Arabic etc...)

I already did ask the question about possible fix for this issue: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/why-does-label-cuts-letters but suggested workarounds are only good for certain cases. They do not solve the whole problem.

**What I know so far:**

1. baselineZero property doesn't work for me. See description here: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/why-does-label-cuts-letters#post-61471
2. Settings baselineFontDescription works but cannot be used as proper workaround - you have to manually measure baselineFontSize all the time. See description here: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/why-does-label-cuts-letters#post-61471

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Ah, now that's a great question! :) I've had problems but fortunately was able to just cut off the letters I need and simply add some spaces where there were vertical cuts. Would love to see the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The workaround i am currently using is to add transparent shadow filter. 
You may ned to increase radius depending on your font.

This is by no means a good solution, just a dirty ***temporary*** fix.

```
 public static function defaultTextRendererFactory():ITextRenderer
 {
    // Transparent shadow helps to avoid clipping on some fonts
    var clipFix:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(0.0, 0.0, 0x000000, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0);
    var textRenderer:TextBlockTextRenderer = new TextBlockTextRenderer();
    textRenderer.nativeFilters = [clipFix];
    return textRenderer;
 }
```

Comment: Oops, i didn't see the question was asked 3 years ago